# Display parentcontact tasks in alert box when form load

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Pre requisite:    --On account record set primary contact to any one contact of your choice    --For the above  contact create two test tasks.    Actual task    Retrieve those tasks using odata in account form save and iterate to show all name attributes in alert popup

```
function dis()
{
var primarycontactid=Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("primarycontactid").getValue()[0].id;
XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.RetrieveMultiple(
    "TaskSet",
    "?$select=Subject&$filter=RegardingObjectId/Id eq guid'+primarycontactid+'",
    function (results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var Description = results[i].Description;
            var Subject = results[i].Subject;
            alert("Description" + Description + " \n subject :" + Subject + "\n success");
        }
    },
    function (error) {
         alert(error.message);
    },
    true
);
}
```

Where have I gone wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function retrieveTask() {

```
var conId=Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("primarycontactid").getValue()[0].id;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/TaskSet?$select=Subject&$filter=RegardingObjectId/Id eq guid'"+conId+"'",
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    async: true,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var results = data.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var Subject = results[i].Subject;
            alert(Subject);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

}

check it. It will work

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, there seem to be some errors in the second parameter of the `RetrieveMultiple`:

`"?$select=Subject&$filter=RegardingObjectId/Id eq guid'+primarycontactid+'",`

should not have the initial `?` and also the quotes look messed up around `primarycontactid`

`"$select=Subject&$filter=RegardingObjectId/Id eq guid'" + primarycontactid + "'",`